# Getting Json object inside a Json object in Java

Tags: java, json

So I have some code that is able to send this out:

```
  {"id":1,
   "method":"addWaypoint",
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "params":[
     {
       "lon":2,
       "name":"name",
       "lat":1,
       "ele":3
     }
    ]
   }
```

The server receives this JSON object as a string named "clientstring":

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(clientstring); //Make string a JSONObject
 String method = obj.getString("method"); //Pulls out the corresponding method
```

Now, I want to be able to get the "params" value of {"lon":2,"name":"name","lat":1,"ele":3} just like how I got the "method".
however both of these have given me exceptions:

```
String params = obj.getString("params");
```

and

```
 JSONObject params = obj.getJSONObject("params");
```

I'm really at a loss how I can store and use {"lon":2,"name":"name","lat":1,"ele":3} without getting an exception, it's legal JSON yet it can't be stored as an JSONObject? I dont understand.

Any help is VERY appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have never used `JSONObject` in java.. I used `play-json`, but it seems like `params` is an array because of the `[`. Can you try `JSONArray - params = obj.getJSONArray("params")`

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that this was the problem this whole time, such a minor thing to overlook! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params` in your case is **not** a [JSONObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/json/JsonObject.html), but it is a [JSONArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html).

So all you need to do is first fetch the `JSONArray` and then fetch the first element of that array as the `JSONObject`.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(clientstring); 
JSONArray params = obj.getJsonArray("params");
JSONObject param1 = params.getJsonObject(0);
```

Comment: @Exception have a look at [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html), might help you

Answer (score 2):

How try like that

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(clientstring);
    JSONArray paramsArr = obj.getJSONArray("params");


    JSONObject param1 = paramsArr.getJSONObject(0);

    //now get required values by key
    System.out.println(param1.getInt("lon"));
    System.out.println(param1.getString("name"));
    System.out.println(param1.getInt("lat"));
    System.out.println(param1.getInt("ele"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here "params" is not an object but an array. So you have to parse using:

```
JSONArray jsondata = obj.getJSONArray("params");

for (int j = 0; j < jsondata.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject obj1 = jsondata.getJSONObject(j);
    String longitude = obj1.getString("lon");
    String name = obj1.getString("name");
    String latitude = obj1.getString("lat");
    String element = obj1.getString("ele");
  }
```